# Flask application not taking all responses

Tags: nginx, flask, google-cloud-platform, uwsgi

im building an app to track changes of contacts in Hubspot via a Webhook.

I deployed the service on Cloud Run (GCP) using the following services:

- A single Docker container listening to port 8080
- Nginx + UWSGI for production purposes
- Flask as a framework to update some external data

The problem i got is that everything is built correctly, but when theres more than one request received to the container (for example 100 contact deletions) only a few of them are being processed.

I though that nginx handled the requests and sent it one per one to my Flask app.

If this is not the case. How can i handle this situation?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Consider asking it on https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use gunicorn to handle more requests, gunicorn runs your flask app with more than one workers.

Just add gunicorn in your **requirements.txt** then put the CMD line to Dockerfile:

```
CMD ["gunicorn","-t 30", "-w3", "-b 0.0.0.0:8080", "app:app"]
```

**-t**  max timeout (in seconds)

**-w**  workers (recommended to keep same with processor cores you have in server)

**-b**  binding adress

**app:app** means run app in app.py so you should edit this according to your flask app.

Comment: UWSGI receives requests and brings them to your internal flask app, since your flask app is running with one process it creates bottleneck for your network. Gunicorn allows you to run flask app as multiple processes which makes your server to serve more clients.

Comment: I'll give it a try then, but should I not remove UWSGI and don't change the nginx.conf file with UWSGI socket etc and just apply Gunicorn as another layer of the Container? Or I should rebuild all of these changes around Gunicorn?

Comment: Well, I have used nginx and gunicorn together before. I would suggest the same for you as well.